# Creating a popup tool bar in a full screen NSOpenGLView (OSX Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa, macos, fullscreen

I have a Cocoa app in which one of my NSOpenGLViews can go into full screen mode (I do this with the method enterFullScreenMode:withOptions:).  I would like to create a little widget that when you mouse over it, a toolbar pops up with some different controls.  I am wondering what would be the best way to implement this widget?  At first I thought about using a panel but I don't think you can bring up any windows when in full screen mode.  Also, it seems that you can't add a subview to an NSOpenGLView?  Are these two assumptions correct?  What else could I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a subview to the openglview's superview.

Comment: Would you have to use layers to do this?

Comment: I was under the impression you can't have overlapping view both be visible without layers.  Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add any subview to NSOpenGLView.
You can use [glViewport](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml) to simulate subviews.